# Failed to load WebMethod

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

My drop down change function works good. But the WebMethod failed to load

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[id*=drpSub]").change(function () {
                var drpSub = $("[id*=drpSub]").val();
                var Gs_Id = $("[id*=ddlClass]").val();
                alert(drpSub);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'assignments1.aspx/GetAssignmentType',
                    data: {},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (r) {
                        //var ddlCustomers = $("[id*=drpType]");
                        //ddlCustomers.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
                        //$.each(r.d, function () {
                        //    ddlCustomers.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                        //});
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

**Code Behind**

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<ListItem> GetAssignmentType()
    {
       string query = "SELECT OP_AssignmentType.AT_Id, OP_AssignmentType.AT_Type + ' (' + CONVERT(varchar(10), COUNT(8)) + ')' AS AT_Type FROM OP_Assignments INNER JOIN OP_AssignmentType ON OP_Assignments.OP_AS_TypeId = OP_AssignmentType.AT_Id WHERE        (OP_Assignments.OP_AS_SubjId = '" + 10 + "') AND (OP_Assignments.OP_GS_IdNo = 37) And OP_AS_LastDate>='" + DateTime.Now + "' GROUP BY OP_AssignmentType.AT_Id, OP_AssignmentType.AT_Type";
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                List<ListItem> customers = new List<ListItem>();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        customers.Add(new ListItem
                        {
                            Value = sdr["Sub_Id"].ToString(),
                            Text = sdr["Subject_Name"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
                return customers;
            }
        }
    }
```

I know code inside the web method may be wrong. My actual problem is, the page is not loading when in put break point in the web method code behind. My console is error free. Is their any fault in my jQuery. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` in your ajax so, your ajax would be like

```
          $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'Default.aspx/GetAssignmentType',
                data: {},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (r) {
                    //var ddlCustomers = $("[id*=drpType]");
                    //ddlCustomers.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
                    //$.each(r.d, function () {
                    //    ddlCustomers.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                    //});
                }
            });
```

Comment: thank you for your replay. This is my new ajax code but i am in the same trouble            url: 'assignments1.aspx/GetAssignmentType',
                    data: {},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'GET',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

Comment: can you please go to network tab and check in browser console ?

Comment: in console  - 
**GET  http://localhost:7322/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0                     assignments1.aspx?sid=1:416**    and in my source i found an error in ajax api as 
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

Comment: not this go to network tab in console and hit F5, you will see list and try to find `GetAssignmentType` and click on it, on right side click on response and check

Comment: sorry sir i have only 1 reputation so cant chat ... cant find the  GetAssignmentType in network under name list ...

Comment: I found GetAssignmentType in network .   **{"Message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","StackTrace":"   at Parent_Assignments.GetAssignmentType() in e:\\Jayakrishnan\\BST My Works\\Parent Portal\\Parent\\assignments1.aspx.cs:line 108","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException"}**

Comment: so it simply means that you already called the method but you have a error on code behind. check you code behind line no 108

Comment: I found the error, mismatch in my connection string with web confic ... Thank you sir for your help and spending this much of time with me ..

Comment: Happy to help you :)